# wxpython HtmlWindow: show full content?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxhtmlwindow

How can I display the full content of a HtmlWindow? I have some HtmlWindows in a scrollable panel and I want to see the full text in these windows. I have tried setting the proportion to 1 and the style to wx.EXPAND, but that doesn't work.
Currently it looks like this:
[image: panel]
But I want to see in the windows the full text:

```
some long text 
with multiple lines 
and another line
```

---

Sample code:

```
import wx
from wx import html
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel


class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.notebook_1 = wx.Notebook(self, -1, style=0)
        self.notebook_1_pane_1 = ScrolledPanel(self.notebook_1, -1)

        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        for _ in xrange(10):
            self.html = html.HtmlWindow(self.notebook_1_pane_1)
            self.html.SetPage('some long text<br />with multiple lines<br />' \
                              'and another line')
            self.html.SetBorders(0)
            self.sizer_3_staticbox = wx.StaticBox(self.notebook_1_pane_1, -1, 
                                                  'a')
            sizer_3 = wx.StaticBoxSizer(self.sizer_3_staticbox, wx.VERTICAL)
            sizer_3.Add(self.html, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
            sizer_2.Add(sizer_3, 0, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        self.notebook_1_pane_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.notebook_1.AddPage(self.notebook_1_pane_1, "tab1")
        sizer_1.Add(self.notebook_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)

        self.notebook_1_pane_1.SetScrollRate(20, 20)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, -1, size=(400, 300))
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to give sizer_2 a proportion of 1 or more as well.

```
sizer_2.Add(sizer_3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
```

This makes the sizer_3 element stretch appropriately too. Otherwise, it only stretches in one direction. I would reduce the number of HTMLWindows you're putting in too unless you're using a high resolution monitor. Expanding this out so that all the text was visible in all the Windows is difficult on these low res wide screens.

Comment: No, I don't think that will work. These HtmlWindows were just examples. They all have a different text in the real program and the number of windows also varies. If I give them all the same proportion, some of them will be too big and some too small. btw, the number of windows doesn't matter, because they are in a ScrolledPanel.